# Jquery Dialog Position not getting properly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have got some problem with this dialog position, actually my requirement is i want to show the dialog in window with `margin-top: 400px;` and width is window  width, height is `600px`.
This code is not working for me!

And i share screen shot also, ineed to show the dialog form middle![enter image description here][1] window instead of top.

```
       $(document).ready(function(){ 
    var wid = $( window ).width();
    var hig = $( document ).height();
    alert(wid +"---"+ hig );

       $('#advoptions').click(function(){

           $('#advpop').dialog({
           modal:true,
           draggable: false,
           resizable: false,
           width: wid,
           height: '600',
           position:['middle',500]



           });             
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way..

```
  $(".myValue").mouseover(function() {
var x = jQuery(this).position().left + jQuery(this).outerWidth();
var y = jQuery(this).position().top - jQuery(document).scrollTop();
jQuery("#dialog").dialog('option', 'position', [x,y]);
});
```

or we can go this route

```
 $('#myMsgx').dialog( 'open' );
 var myMsgX = $(this).position().left - $(this).outerWidth();
 var mymsgY = $(this).position().top - ( $(document).scrollTop() + $('.ui-dialog').outerHeight() );
$('#myMsgx').dialog( 'option', 'position', [myMsgX, myMsgY] );
```

Comment: Not error, i won't get exact position. It overrides the top value to zero, finally i got it in some other way by adding dynamic inline css instead of jquery Dialog position options.

Comment: If you resolved the problem post the answer here it will be helpful to others